# How to get the voters from a particular proxy account?

Tags: accounts, voting, proxy

How to fetch the lists of accounts who delegate their votes to a particular proxy account?

If there isn't any direct way to retrieve the list, is there suggestions how to aggregate data and filter out the result?

Answer (score 0):

Eosauthority offer such a service, you can see all the voters of a particular proxy account on their page: https://eosauthority.com/vote/proxies

Comment: Is there a way to get a full list of voters? Only the top 30 voters per proxy are shown.

Answer (score 0):

`voters` table of eosio system contract doesn't have secondary index to allow user to make a query with proxy name. You had better make a watcher observing eosio::voteproducer (eg. By demux) so as to build your own DB for it.